# ItextSharp read textbox text

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to read PDF files using ItextSharp, however I have noticed that the text included in a textbox is not read.

Please any advise.

```
 PdfDictionary pagedic = pdfRead.GetPageN(page);
 PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.ANNOTS));
 if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0)
      continue;
 string Title = "";
 string Title2 = "";
 string Content2 = "";
 foreach (PdfObject A in annotarray.ArrayList)
 {
     PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);
     Title2 += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T).ToString() + "\n";
     if (AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS)!=null)
     {
         Content2 += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS).ToString() + "\n";
     }
     if (AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T)!=null)
     {
         Title += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T).ToString() + "\n";
     }
     if (AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T)!=null)
     {
         txt += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T).ToString() + "\n";
     }                    
     if (AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS)!=null)
     {
         txt += PdfName.CONTENTS.ToString() + "\n";
     }
     txt += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.NOTE) + "\n";
     txt += AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.FREETEXT)+"\n";
 }
 MessageBox.Show(txt);
 MessageBox.Show(Title);
 MessageBox.Show(Title2);
 MessageBox.Show(Content2);
```

Comment: Which text box are you talking about? Please be more precise about the type of annotation you are referring to.

Comment: If you are talking about text fields, please throw away your code, and read some documentation. Form fields of type text that are represented by widget annotations looking like a text box, don't store their value in `/Contents`, but in `/V`. Also, you shouldn't get that value from the widget annotation dictionaries, but from the field dictionaries. The iText code to get the value of a text field in an AcroForm is much easier than what you have now, but it is unclear if you are talking about text fields or text annotations.

Comment: You are right, I am trying to read the text fields. thank you for your comment. I will post it when I finish it.

Comment: Actually these are markup annotation. However the above code can read titles,author and Content of textboxs and comment boxes. However I have some PDF files where I can not read the content . The value of the content is null. I have tried /V but it's also null. this has no relation with text fields.

Comment: OK, can you share the PDF with the annotations you can't read? The content of an annotation can be stored in different entries depending on the actual type of annotation.

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/75274ef8f329ebcb9ae2d694f9c99910.html

Comment: @BrunoLowagie please note that if I edited one of the comments manually, then I am able to read the content of the text Box ( AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that I was reading the content as string, 
where it should not be. as in below.
[Content Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbiQw.png)
so using ToUnicodeString() solved the issue.

```
annotation.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS).ToUnicodeString();
```